# SQL - get sum of values from top 20 percent per category

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

this one is tricky.

Finance table has SecurityID, FundID, and Value already grouped by FundID and ranked/sorted within each FundID

It might look like this (imagine hundreds or records):

```
+------+------------+--------+-------+
| Rank | SecurityID | FundID | Value |
+------+------------+--------+-------+
| 1    | 23         | A      | 5     |
| 2    | 43         | A      | 4     |
| 3    | 44         | A      | 3     |
| 1    | 72         | B      | 8     |
| 2    | 75         | B      | 7     |
| 3    | 76         | B      | 2     |
| 1    | 83         | C      | 5     |
+------+------------+--------+-------+
```

Goal is to get the top 20% of securities in each fund type. Then get the sum of the values from that 20%. For example, if there are 10 securities in Fund type A, then I want to sum up the values from the top 2 records. The answer is 9.

The SQL might look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Value) as TopTwenty, FundID
                        FROM @FinanceTable    
                        WHERE Rank <= ((SELECT  COUNT(*)
                                                FROM @FinanceTable WHERE FundID = 1) * .20)

                        GROUP BY FundID
```

The query above works for FundID = 1. However, I don't want to specify "Where FundID = 1". Instead, I want it to run this query for all the FundIDs. This is the part where I am stumped. I think I can do it using a cursor. But is there a way to do so without a cursor?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you improve the title? I doubt anyone is ever going to search for "tricky SQL Server query". They would probably search for, "Get percentage of rows and sum their values in SQL Server" or somesuch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with FundCounts As
(
    Select FundID, Count(*) * 0.2 As TopTwentyCount
    From Finance
    Group By FundID
)
select F.FundID, Sum(Value) as TopTwentyValueSum
from Finance F
inner join FundCounts FC on F.FundID = FC.FundID
where F.[Rank] <= FC.TopTwentyCount 
group by F.FundID
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the window function `count(*)` to get the total number of rows for each fund.  Then use a `where` clause for the filtering:

```
select FundID, sum(value)
from (select ft.*, count(*) over (partition by FundId) as cnt
      from @FinanceTable ft
     ) ft
where rank <= 0.2*cnt
group by FundId;
```

Comment: Gordon, thank you. But I had some trouble with ft.* ??? Someone gave you an upvote so it probably works. I ended up using @amit_g's answer below.

Comment: @nanonerd . . . It was just a missing alias on the subquery.